# Emit Event/Subscribe to a TypeScript method (regular TypeScript file) in an AngularJs TypeScript controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

How can I subscribe/or listen to an `event/method` in a regular `TypeScript` file that is part of our `AngularJs TypeScript` project?

**Context**: We have a loader, `progressBar.ts` with a `method`, `updateGlobalProgressBar`, that is exposed via the `export attribute`, that keeps track of the percentage loaded. On the other hand I have a `controller`, `ribbonController`, that sets certain `properties` of the ribbon `view`.

Is there a way I can subscribe or listen to the `updateGlobalProgressBar` `method` in my `ribbonController`, to know when the loader has reached 100%?

**Please note**: the `progressBar.ts` is not an `AngularJs service` or `controller`, but a plain `TypeScript` file with nothing being `injected`, no `constructor method` etc.

I have tried a `do while loop`, but this created an endless `loop`:

```
do {
    this._scope.loaderHasLoaded = utilities.loadingComplete();
}
while (this._scope.loaderHasLoaded === false);
```

I have tried an `if loop`, but this only fired once, and obviously not at the right time:

```
if (utilities.loadingComplete()) {
    this._scope.loaderHasLoaded = true;
} else {
    this._scope.loaderHasLoaded = false;
}
```

I need to somehow listen to a `variable` or something in the `progressBar.ts` to inform me when the load is done. I wrote the following helper `method` that gets called when the load is complete from within the `updateGlobalProgressBar`:

```
export function loadingComplete(): boolean {
    if (this.loadComplete === true) {
        return true
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

I can call this `method` etc, but don't know how to `subscribe` to it?

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will attempt to help you out.

Approach:

1. create event emitters in progressBar.ts that emit events when the progress bar reaches 100% status.
2. expose the event via export attribute.
3. subscribe/listen to the event and perform necessary actions.
4. Trigger event
5. clean up

Now, I will elaborate with some code:

1. create event emitters in progressBar.ts that emit events when the progress bar reaches 100% status.

   Basic event emitter class and instance creation:

   class EventEmitter {

   ```
           listeners=[];

           register(callback) {

               var _listeners = this.listeners

               _listeners.push(callback);

               return function() {
                   _listeners.splice(_listeners.indexOf(callback), 1);
               }

           }

           trigger() {
               var args =arguments;
               this.listeners.forEach(callback => callback.apply(null, args));
           }
       }


       const onProgressBarComplete = new EventEmitter();
   ```
2. expose the event via export attribute

export onProgressBarComplete;

3. subscribe/listen to the event and perform necessary actions.

   ```
   import {onProgressBarComplete} from './progressBar';

   var unListenToEvent = onProgressBarComplete.register(function() {
       // code in response to event
   });
   ```
4. trigger Event: In updateGlobalProgressBar method add condition

   ```
   if(progress === 100) { //This condition is up to you
       onProgressBarComplete.trigger();
   }
   ```
5. clean up.

   when you are no longer interested in the event remove subscirption by executing:

   unListenToEvent();

Hope This points you in the right direction.
Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for your help! Appreciated.